# Tab bar button in the navigation not visible

Tags: ios, button, navigation, viewcontroller, tabbar

I am developing a simple app with tab bar functionalities.
When I press on one of the three tab bar items, the added bar button in the navigation of my table view controller don't appear. I've added also a logout button, which either dont appear.
I dont udnerstand this, when added a button/tab bar in the interface builder it should automatically make this visible, right?!

here you can see my mainstoryboard
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hQjuJxESVq9c0rWWlURkcF3ckd5Hjga1p468rDxWe1U/edit?usp=sharing

I noticed when I change the "little arrow" in the mainstoryboard to the tabbarcontroller, the buttons appear. I think my rootviewcontroller is not the tabbarcontroller itself, it dont show the buttons. But there should be an other alternative to show the buttons in table view controllers, even when the tabbarcontroller is not the rootviewcontroller?

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: I added the bar button with interface builder. I have not set a class for the tab bar yet.

Comment: I noticed when I change the "little arrow" in the mainstoryboard to the tabbarcontroller, the buttons appear. I think my rootviewcontroller is not the tabbarcontroller itself, it dont show the buttons. But there should be an other alternative to show the buttons in table view controllers, even when the tabbarcontroller is not the rootviewcontroller?